# Is there a point to destroying Mr. Freeze's wives?

Tags: batman-arkham-city

In New Game Plus I finally beat Mr. Freeze, but this time I noticed that there were various statues of Nora around that I could destroy with a baterang or by dodging when he shot at me with one behind me. I tried destroying all that I could find, but it didn't seem to do anything. Is there a point to them or are they just eye candy?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

During the fight, destroying the Nora statues irritates Freeze and indicates to him where you are. This could be used to draw him to a statue location and setup an attack.

Comment: To where you are or the statue? Because I can destroy one from the other side of the room.

Comment: He follows the statues.

Comment: You'd think he'd know better.